# Cannot install meteor-cordova in PhoneGap applications

Tags: cordova, meteor

Trying to run a meteor app as a mobile application. So I found [Meteor-cordova][1] . I had already created the phonegap applicaiton from xcode. And in the terminal I went into the main project, not the `www` (not sure if that is correct) and then I ran

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/raix/Meteor-cordova.git
```

But got this error

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/util/plugins.js:28
tmp_dir = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'plugman-tmp');
                       ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'tmpdir'
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/util/plugins.js:28:28)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
at require (module.js:378:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/fetch.js:3:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an app using phonegap, you should install plugins using phonegap, not cordova:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/raix/Meteor-cordova.git
```